# Angular 7 Sort Observable.subscribe() by date?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Trying to sort an array of returned Observable.subscribe() data ... new to Angular 7. I'm confused about how to use RXJS methods here, where I need to import what, and how to sort the array of type Event.

Event.ts

```
import {Venue} from './Venue';

export class Event {
  id: number;
  url: string;
  date: string;
  venue_id: number;
  venue: Venue;
}
```

EventResultObj.ts

```
import {Event} from './Event';

export interface EventResultObj {
  count: number;
  next?: any;
  previous?: any;
  results: Event[];
}
```

EventsService.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Event } from '../models/Event';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EventsService {
  eventsUrl = 'http://localhost:4200/assets/tempData/events.json';
  constructor(  private http: HttpClient) { }

  getEvents(): Observable<EventResultObj> {    
    return this.http.get<EventResultObj>(this.eventsUrl).pipe(
          /// CANNOT FIGURE OUT HOW TO GET A SORT FUNCTION TO WORK HERE 
          /// WITH THE OBSERVABLE
    )
  }
}
```

EventsList.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {EventsService} from '../../services/events.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-buyer-events-list',
  templateUrl: './buyer-events-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./buyer-events-list.component.scss']
})
export class BuyerEventsListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private eventsService: EventsService) {
  }

  events;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.eventsService.getEvents().subscribe(events => this.events = events); // OR DO I ADD A PIPE OR MAP HERE AND HOW DO I DO IT?
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You would need to sort it in your service and subscribe in the component, so your service will have somehting like,

```
 getEvents(): Observable<Event[]> {    
    return this.http.get<Event[]>(this.eventsUrl).pipe(
        map(events => events.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date).getTime() - new Date(a.date).getTime()))
    ) ;
  }
```

and then,

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.eventsService.getEvents().subscribe(events => this.events = events); 
  }
```

Comment: Beat me to it, nice!

Comment: I feel dumb but can't get this to work. Added EventResultsObj to the original question, maybe that's the issue because I keep getting the error "Property 'sort' does not exist on type 'EventsResultObj'". I'm assuming it's because I'm trying to sort something that's not an array, but I'm lost here. Help! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I would add a `map` to sort the events directly in the `getEvents` function in your service. That way, every class using the service will get an observable of your events already sorted:

```js
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

getEvents(): Observable<Event[]> {    
  return this.http.get<Event[]>(this.eventsUrl).pipe(
    map(events => events.sort((a: Event, b: Event) =>
      (new Date(a.date)).getTime() - (new Date(b.date)).getTime()
    ))
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In service you use pipe and map!

```
public getEvents(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.eventsUrl).pipe(map(response => response));
```

}

In your component use subscribe!

```
this.eventsService.getEvents()
 .subscribe(events => {
   console.log(events); // Example
 }, err => {
   throw err;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. I would use the tap operator.

```html
const  sortById = function(data) {
  data.sort((a,b) => data.id - data.id);
};


getEvents(): Observable<Event[]> {    
  return this.http.get<Event[]>(this.eventsUrl)
    .pipe(tap(sortById))
}
```